# Error when trying to create many to many relationship between objects

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, graphql-java

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between users and movie, so that a user could have a favorite movie list. I am also using GraphQL for my API queries. I have been following a GraphQL tutorial which includes a many to many relationship.

This is the error I am currently getting:

```
2020-06-02 18:12:05.429  WARN 20640 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table favorites drop foreign key FKpbtimrfu4b5fna6esnqfj0e3y" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table favorites drop foreign key FKpbtimrfu4b5fna6esnqfj0e3y" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

favorites.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "favorites")
public class Favorite {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private Long movieId;
}
```

user.java:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String token;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "favorites", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movieId") })
    private List<Movie> favorites;
}
```

movie.java:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="movies")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private int length;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Movie> favorites;
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/innodb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

[image: Favorites table]

[image: Movies_favorites]

Not sure what is causing this error, also not sure if this is how to establish the relationship that I want.

Comment: Can you just try to give the actual column name as in table instead of Java Entity Variable name? joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movieId")  --> joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") ?

Comment: For me below works as expected:  public class Account {
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Account.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "accounts", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_request_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") })
  private Set<Account> accounts;

 public class AccountRequest {
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "accounts", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = AccountRequest.class)
  private Set<AccountRequest> accountRequests;

Comment: Ok ill get that a try. Also, why is spring creating a table movies_favorites?

Comment: Because many to many relations require one extra table where both the table records are mapped. I noticed one more problem - In the User class you need to change  @JoinTable(name="movies" and private List<Movie> favorites;